# How can I take the log of a column in Python using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the the following `df`:

```
0        4.20
1        6.30
2       74.90
3       83.45
4       17.19
5       74.34
6     1717.73
7      139.05
8      753.36
9        4.54
10      60.07
Name: exports, dtype: float64
```

I would like take logs of the whole column, but when I try:

```
import numpy as np
lexports=np.log(df['exports'])
```

..I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log'`

How can I fix this? I looked up other threads. They seem to explore causes, but don't provide solutions.

Comment: it works fine for me. Did you try to run it on other columns?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, just tried and same error message unfortunately.

Comment: Have you named any variable as np?
What happens if you type np in your console?
Try del np and import numpy again

Comment: @IoaTzimas, that was it. A collaborated added variable in the second part named 'np'. That was it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Great, i will add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you have used np as name for some other variable (of type integer)

You can run

```
del np
```

and

```
import numpy as np
```

again, and it will work